# Parsing RSS with Perl and XML::XPath

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, rss

I am completely lost and do not understand RSS/XML parsing at all. It make no sense to me whatsoever.

Here is the Perl script I am hacking away with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use XML::XPath;
use Data::Dumper;

my $rssurl      = "http://librivox.org/rss/4273";
my $xml = get($rssurl);
my $xp = XML::XPath->new( xml => $xml );
my $stories = $xp->find( '/' );

foreach my $story( $stories->get_nodelist ) {
    print "----\n";
    my $title = $xp->find( 'title', $story )->string_value;
    print "title is [$title]\n";
}
```

The biggest mystery to me is what do I pass to `$xp->find()` I am just guess and grasping at straws.  Isn't there a way I can just `find` everything and iterate over whatever was `found`?

Comment: Why not using something RSS aware? https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Feed

Comment: because it won't install on my system.

Comment: What do you mean "won't install"? What problems are you having?

Comment: Anyways.  I gave up on trying parse rss with Perl and was able to accomplish my task with Python and Beautifulsoup.  Beautifulsoup is awesome! BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XML::XPath::find` takes an [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as input and returns a `XML::XPath::Nodeset` object, which you can iterate over.

```
$stories = $xp->find( '//channel/item' );  # find all <channel><item>
foreach my $story ($stories->get_nodelist) {
    my $titles = $story->find( 'title' );  # a set, even if there's only 1 elem
    foreach my $title ($titles->get_nodelist) {
        print "title is ", $title->string_value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have an answer using `XML::Feed`, but I thought it was worth resolving this too.

You need to get used to the XPath syntax. This [*10-Minute XPath Tutorial*](http://oreilly.com/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-xpath-utorial.html) is a good swift introduction. XPath expressions are essentially similar to file system paths, with a few additions.

Looking at the XML from your feed, the root element is `rss`, within which is a `channel`, containing a number of `item` elements. It is these you are looking for, so the XPath expression is just `/rss/channel/item`.

You don't need to use the original `XML::XPath` object to call `find`: each `XML::XPath::Node::Element` object that has come from a previous call to `find` has its own `find` method that does exactly what you have written, so you can just write `$item->find('title')`, which will return a `XML::XPath::NodeSet`.

Furthermore, `XML::XPath::NodeSet` has stringify overridden as a call to `to_literal`, so there is also no need for your `string_value` call.

This code does what you intended. I hope it helps.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;
use XML::XPath;

my $rssurl = "http://librivox.org/rss/4273";
my $xml    = get($rssurl);
my $xp     = XML::XPath->new( xml => $xml );
my @items  = $xp->findnodes('/rss/channel/item');

foreach my $item (@items) {
  print "----\n";
  my $title = $item->find('title');
  print "title is <<$title>>\n";
}
```

**output**

```
----
title is <<1 - Section 1>>
----
title is <<2 - Section 2>>
----
title is <<3 - Section 3>>
----
title is <<4 - Section 4>>
```